# Docker image builds, but doesn't run

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, tomcat6, libreplan

I am trying to create a docker build for [libreplan](http://www.libreplan.com), using the install instructions [here](http://www.libreplan.org/INSTALL.html#libreplan-manual-installation).  The dockerfile is

```
FROM tomcat:6

RUN apt-get -yq update && apt-get -yq install \
  cutycapt \
  patch \
  postgresql-client \
  libpg-java \
  xvfb

# Prepare webapp location
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/libreplan
# Get WAR file
RUN wget -q -O /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/libreplan/libreplan.war http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libreplan/LibrePlan/libreplan_1.3.0.war
# Install libreplan.xml
ADD libreplan.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/libreplan/libreplan.xml
# Patch the policy to include libreplan
ADD catalina.policy.patch catalina.policy.patch
RUN patch -o /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.policy catalina.policy.patch

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

The build works but doesn't do anything when I try to run it.  All the code is on [github](https://github.com/aquavitae/docker-libreplan) and I have set up an automated build on the [docker registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/aquavitae/libreplan/).  Included in the repo is a sample docker-compose.yml which should work, but when I try it no output is shown from the libreplan container and I can't access it through a browser.  I don't know tomcat at all so it is probably something that I have done wrong, but I don't know how to even start figuring out what.  Is there anything obvious that I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your image:

```
$ docker run --name libreplan aquavitae/libreplan
```

I get:

```
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 387 ms
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.44
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory host-manager
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory manager
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory libreplan
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/12  config=null
May 28, 2015 4:57:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 580 ms
```

Which seems entirely successful.  Furthermore, I can grab the ip
address of the container:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' libreplan
172.17.0.9
```

And the open that in a browser:

```
$ firefox http://172.17.0.9:8080
```

And see the default Tomcat web page.

So mostly it seems to work.

I can also `docker up` things without error, although I replaced the `build: .` line with `image: aquavitae/libreplan` because I wasn't patient enough to try the build.

Comment: Weird, I just tried rebuilding locally and it worked - maybe a caching issue.  However, the actual webapp still doesn't seem to be accessible.  Any idea what I've done wrong with installing it into tomcat?

Comment: That's more of a Tomcat issue, and I'm not particularly familar with Tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

OK in this situation you have to troubleshoot by running a shell in the container and starting up the process manually. If you're lucky `docker logs containername` may have enough information for you to understand what's wrong, but usually I end up having to get into the container as follows:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --link db:db <containerid> bash
```

Once in, you,ll want to run your CMD directly.

```
catalina.sh run
```

Looking at your file, my first thought would be `catalina.sh` is not in your PATH or not executable. So you would fix that by running `/bin/sh /full/path/to/catalina.sh run`, or adjusting your PATH environment variable and/or using the WORKDIR directive in your Dockerfile.